# Unable to set width of a border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have set two paragraphs in **HTML**:

> Note that the width in both `p` and `p1` are the same:

```css
p {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-style: double;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 2cm 2cm;
}

p1 {
  font-family: impact;
  font size: 20px;
  border-style: groove;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 2cm 2cm;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<p1>This is another paragraph</p1>
```

However, when previewing in a web browser, the width of the borders appear different. What's causing this?

If I change `width` in `p1` to a different value, the width of the border in preview does not change either. But I am able to adjust width of `p` as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p1` isn't HTML element, use class instead.

Or if you want to create custom element Read about HTML **[custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements)**

```css
p {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-style: double;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 2cm 2cm;
}

.p1 {
  font-family: impact;
  font size: 20px;
  border-style: groove;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 2cm 2cm;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<p class=p1>This is another paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, `p1` is a custom tag and won't inherit the attributes of a block element.

You have to manually assign `display: block` to `p1` for it to behave as a block level element.

```css
p {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-style: double;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 2cm 2cm;
}

p1 {
  font-family: impact;
  font size: 20px;
  border-style: groove;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 2cm 2cm;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<p1>This is another paragraph</p1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class or ID to your second paragraph as `p1` is not a HTML element.

When selecting a class in CSS use a period before it. When selecting an ID, use a #.

```
<p class=p1>This is another paragraph</p>

.p1 {
  xxx
}
```

or

```
<p id=p1>This is another paragraph</p>

#p1 {
  xxx
}
```